# CMD Syntax for local command

Tags: cmd, rundll32

I would like to run a script, copy my folder and start rundll32 in my copied folder.

```
mkdir "c:\SmartCard_Treiber"
xcopy "%~DP0SmartCard_Treiber\*" "c:\SmartCard_Treiber" /i /s


cmd /c cd "c:\SmartCard_Treiber" & RUNDLL32.EXE AdvPack.dll,LaunchINFSection Gemalto.inf,,0


TIMEOUT /T 30 /NOBREAK 
rd "C:\SmartCard_Treiber" /Q /S
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir "c:\SmartCard_Treiber"
xcopy "%~DP0SmartCard_Treiber\*" "c:\SmartCard_Treiber" /i /s
pushd "c:\SmartCard_Treiber"
RUNDLL32.EXE AdvPack.dll,LaunchINFSection Gemalto.inf,,0
TIMEOUT /T 30 /NOBREAK 
popd
rd "C:\SmartCard_Treiber" /Q /S
```

Change to the needed directory (`pushd`) and when finished return to the previous one (`popd`)

Comment: Thank you, was using SCCM to deploy this Commands, so i forgot to disable x64 File Systems.